# Do all rationals $\left ( \mathbb{Q} \right )$ form a perfect set if the metric space is $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The following question came to my mind while reading the definition of a perfect set from Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd Edition, Page 32, Section 2.18(h):

> If the metric space is the set of all rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ (instead of $\mathbb R^1$ -- the set of all real numbers), then does $\mathbb Q$ constitute a perfect set?

In my understanding, the answer is "yes". Because $\mathbb Q$ is closed (since $\mathbb Q$ contains each of its limit points if the underlying metric space is $\mathbb Q$) and because every point of $\mathbb Q$ is a limit point of $\mathbb Q$ (arbitrary proximity). I'm not feeling so much sure somehow, and didn't find a corroboration elsewhere. Therefore this query.

Would appreciate help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly right.

Of course, most *applications* of perfect sets (that I'm aware of anyways) require the ambient space to be "reasonable," usually completely metrizable, and in such spaces perfect sets are very unlike $\mathbb{Q}$ (e.g. uncountable). But if we do take $\mathbb{Q}$ to be our ambient space, then yes, in that context $\mathbb{Q}$ is perfect.

(Note incidentally that perfectness makes sense, not just in the context of metric spaces, but more general [topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space).)

Comment: I'll be in my office tomorrow, if you want to have a chat.